# Chromium wasting too many resources(chromium browser --enable-pinch)

Tags: linux, memory, browser, process, chromium

I use chromium browser [Version 87.0.4280.66 (Official Build) Built on Ubuntu, running on elementary 5.1.7 (64-bit)] in my PC on elementary OS. I recently noted that a process by chromium is taking up too much of my memory even when it is closed. The process is *chromium-browser --enable-pinch*. I looked up the process in google and found out that it is used for touch purposes which is unnecessary for me since I use Desktop PC without any touch capabilities. So I would like to know if there is a way to stop this process permanently within chromium.

I tried `chrome://flags/#touch-events` but I couldn't find any option to disable it there (there isn't even any entry with 'touch').

[image: Screenshot of Processes]

Comment: Try something similar `/usr/bin/chromium-browser --no-touch-pinch --disable-session-crashed-bubble --no-first-run 'http://localhost:3000'`

Comment: @Alex_Krug  Tried running it now in terminal as root and user, but doesn't seem to make any changes. Anything I did wrong?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22999829/disable-chrome-pinch-zoom-for-use-in-kiosk